# replace string in one file from string in other file in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have config_file.txt has next structure

```
host ='myserver'
login = 'vasya'
password = 'pupkin'
```

and code.scala has next structure

```
var_host = '***HOST***'
var_login = '***LOGIN***'
var_password = '***PASS***'
```

both files are in the same directory.
i need to take appropriate line in config file and replace with it appropriate line in code file
I was looking at grep function but do not . know if there is way do what i need or is there other functions which can be used to do such a job ?

Thank YOU !

Comment: Grep only does matching it doesn't do replacement. You'll need to use `awk` for this.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort. You should start by performing a search. The question has been asked and answered may times.

Comment: @Barmar multiple combined calls of grep can do this job :)

Comment: @jww Really? This looks like an actual problem that someone would have with application configuration files.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes. College courses often use examples similar to real world use cases.

Comment: @jww no its not homework I graduate in 2013 , just do not know bash on that level and have noone to ask. I check question and there was nothin that . can answer my question

Comment: The site should offer a mechanical turk badge for those who get others to do their work for them. Maybe call it the Tom Sawyer badge because he got Huckleberry Finn to paint the fence for him.

Comment: @ jww please stop complaining, if you don't like something just send your request to support .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick little perl script that does it:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

our %vars;

BEGIN {
  my $config_file = "config_file.txt";
  GetOptions("config=s" => \$config_file) or die "Invalid argument\n";
  open my $config, "<", $config_file or die "Unable to open $config_file\n";
  while (<$config>) {
    if (/^(\w+)\s*=\s*('.*')/) {
      $vars{$1} = $2;
    }
  }
  close $config;
}

if (/^var_(\w+)\s*=/) {
  $_ = "var_$1 = $vars{$1}\n" if exists $vars{$1}
}
```

Run like so:

```
$ perl set_vars.pl code.scala
```

and set the name of the config file to something other than "config_file.txt" with

```
$ perl set_vars.pl --config=foo.txt code.scala
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you're wondering why it's probably because you answered a poorly written question.

Comment: @Barmar I stopped wondering or caring about downvotes a long time ago.

Comment: Good for you, me too!

Comment: @Shawn thanks, but . how script . will know which line use as which variable an my scala file ?

Comment: @Shawn I didn't use it , decide to go Python, but . still thank you for your offer